# using tensorflow retrained graph in OpenCV-3.4 in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I started using tensorflow recently & referred to the tensorflow transfer learning tutorial from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3 and retrained the InceptionV3 model with my own image data. In python I was able to train model and classify images both on Windows 10 and  Ubuntu-16.04.

I need to use the retrained model in C++.

- Windows 10 
  -Python 3.5 
  -OpenCV3.4 
  -Visual Studio 2017

I'm using the code sample https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_inception.cpp
As per this tutorial, I'm supposed to use the inception5, but I need to use InceptionV3.
This is how I load the retrained graph, class name files and config files.

```
String modelFile="//tf_files/retrained_graph.pb";
String classNamesFile = "//tf_files/retrained_labels.txt";
String config = "//tf_files/retrained_graph.pb";
```

The code throws an error at

```
    dnn::Net net = readNetFromTensorflow(modelFile);
```

**Error details:**

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE263D7788 in ReadModel.exe: Microsoft
>   C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000003B780FB3A0.
>   occurred

**Command line output:**

> DecodeJpeg:DecodeJpeg(DecodeJpeg/contents) acceptable_fraction:[ ]
>   channels:[ ] fancy_upscaling:[ ] try_recover_truncated:[ ]
>   dct_method:[ ] ratio:[ ] OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Unknown
>   layer type DecodeJpeg in op DecodeJpeg) in
>   cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet,
>   file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp,
>   line 1487

What I understood that I need to remove some of the information from the retrained graph.
I googled about these errors and possible solutions, but none helped. Looks like freeze_graph.py available at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py might help, but I can not use it as I don't know from where to get the checkpoints. 
Please help me to resolve this issue. I will appreciate it.

Comment: coder999, please take a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/175699/readnetfromtensorflow-fails-on-retrained-nn/ .

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I will follow these steps.

Comment: Following the link mentioned. Downloaded tensorflow from git, but not able to find ~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \ Can you please help again? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#using-the-graph-transform-tool

Comment: Dmitry thanks again. It worked.